# Using a VPN on a PS4, but not on other devices on the same network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, internet

**The current setup is:**

A residence has an internet service provider, providing internet through Coaxial Cable connected to a modem/router combination box also provided by the ISP. There are 2 devices with wired connections to the modem/router, a laptop used for business (which cannot, under any circumstances, be connected to my private VPN or the PS4 in any way other than on the same router/network), and the PS4 itself. There are various and sundry other devices (a personal laptop {which does NOT have an ethernet port}, smartphones, tablets, etc., used by various household members) connected, periodically and intermittently, through WiFi connections, to the same modem/router. There is no VPN provider, currently. There are no WiFi extenders, secondary routers, etc., currently.

**The desired outcome should be:**

I would like to be able to add as little cost, and as little hardware, as possible, while still allowing the PS4 to connect to the internet through a VPN connection occasionally, but not constantly. And without affecting the internet connections of any of the other devices that may be connected before, during, and after, the PS4 is connected or disconnected from the VPN.

Can this be accomplished without additional hardware? If so, how? If not, why not?

Comment: *"Can this be accomplished without additional hardware?"* -- My suspicion would be no. It sounds like you would need at least something like an old laptop or Raspberry Pi to act as a server for your VPN software. I believe the basic order to isolate the PS4 in the manner desired would be Router -> VPN server -> PS4.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Would a second router work?  IPS Router > personal router > PS4 (all connected by ethernet)?

Comment: It would likely depend on the router/IPS device capabilities (it would probably need to be able to run any VPN software or otherwise have the capability to route VPN vs. non-VPN traffic).

Comment: @Anaksunaman The laptop used for work also has a VPN function/software installed by the employer who is also providing that laptop. The work computer is routinely connected and disconnected from the employer's work VPN service, all while maintaining its wired connection to the ISP device/router.  Is this enough to know whether or not the ISP provided modem/router is capable of what you described?